# Only filtering in Shiny if every option is selected

Tags: r, shiny

I have finally figured out how to get the plot to react to user input...unfortunately, the user needs to select the Year range, the Golfer, and the Course at the moment. I want them to be able to filter by just year and golfer, or just year and course if they want. How can I fix my code so that it returns the plot even if something isn't filled out? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm still pretty new at this! Thanks!

## Define server logic required to draw a histogram

```
    server <- function(input, output, session) {

    updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = 'golfer', choices = dkDatabase$Golfer, selected = "Woodland, Gary", server = TRUE)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = 'course', choices = dkDatabase$Course, server = TRUE)

    output$points <- renderPlot({
    dkDatabase %>%
    filter(dkDatabase$Year >= input$year[1],
         dkDatabase$Year <= input$year[2],
         dkDatabase$Golfer == input$golfer,
         dkDatabase$Course == input$course) %>%
    ggplot(aes(dkPoints)) + geom_histogram(fill="green", colour = "black") +
    xlab("DK Points") +
    ylab("Events")
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a bit more of the code I can't really test this, but it should work with some small modifications.

In the ui code, set your default select input:

```
selectInput(..., Choose = '')
```

And then in your server side code add an if statement (can't recall off the top of my head if you would be using single quotes, double quotes or null- test all of them out and 1 should work):

```
if (input$golfer == '') {
dkDatabase %>% 
filter(dkDatabase$Year >= input$year[1],
         dkDatabase$Year <= input$year[2], 
         dkDatabase$Course == input$course)
} 
else if (input$Course == ''){
dkDatabase %>%
filter(dkDatabase$Year >= input$year[1],
         dkDatabase$Year <= input$year[2], 
         dkDatabase$Golfer == input$golfer)
}
else {
dkDatabase %>%
    filter(dkDatabase$Year >= input$year[1],
         dkDatabase$Year <= input$year[2], 
         dkDatabase$Golfer == input$golfer,
         dkDatabase$Course == input$course)
}

output$points <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(aes(dkPoints())) + geom_histogram(fill="green", colour = "black") +
    xlab("DK Points") +
    ylab("Events")
  })
```

I didn't address what to do if the year isn't entered above, but what I would do is automatically set the start and end dates to include all of the data, and then the user can change as desired.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the problem is that I need to select "year", pick a golfer, and pick a course. I want to be able to only select two of them and leave the third option blank and still have the graph show up. As of now, if you don't select all three, it doesn't show anything in the plot.

Comment: So what should the data display if one of the filters isn't selected? i.e. if a year isn't selected, should it display all years? Or all golfers? Can you update your question with a bit more clarity on the logic? It sounds like you will need to include in if else statement in your server side to make this work. I'll update my answer if I understand the logic a bit better.

Comment: Yea, sorry...like I mentioned I'm very new at this. If I picked just the time frame and the golfer, I want all of the dkPoints to be plotted on the histogram. Right now, it only creates a histogram if every option is filled in. I want the user to be able to see the dkPoints histogram based on the filters selected regardless of how many of the options are selected. Not sure if that's more clear.